# How I can import db(archive) neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have archive(tar.gz) which was dumped from production neo4j server. Now I want to get this db locally in my computer. I did it in several steps:

1. I was maked this command: `neo4j-admin load --from=<archive-path> --database=<database> [--force]`(I did it correct, set path to my archive and gave name for database)

2.When I  maked previous command then folder in data/databases appeared, that's cool, I thought

3. Next I was change active db I changed this value:

   `dbms.active_database=graph.db.test`
4. And when all must work I typed "./neo4j console" it started in localhost:7474 I see that db is my,for example "test" db but all was empty. No node labels, no relations and when I used simple command "MATCH(n) RETURN n" there are no records. But I totally sure that it's must to be not empty.

*Question:*
What I did incorrect and what I need to do to make it works?

Comment: Share the `neo4j-admin load` command you used with the parameter values.

Comment: I used it like that: sudo ./neo4j-admin load --from=test.db.tar.gz --database=test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are having problems with the param `database` and the value of `dbms.active_database` property.

Try using the same value for both:

```
bin/neo4j-admin load --from=/backups/graph.db/2016-10-02.dump --database=graph.test.db --force
```

and

```
dbms.active_database=graph.test.db
```

after it, restart Neo4j.

Answer (score -1):

You may try refreshing and re-entering your credentials. Also, it may be the case that your file might not be unzipped properly.